# Is it possible to read ids one at a time without using rownum? (oracle optimization)

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle11g

Basically, I have a loop (in java) that looks up each id from a table and does a few things with it. In each loop, it interacts with the database a few times. It performed slower than I wanted so I logged each interaction with the DB. I found that this sql down below took much more time than other sqls.

```
select id from (select id,rownum as rn from person_info) where rn=#{rowNum}
```

This is the start of the loop where I need to get the id first before doing other things. I'm using rownum here because I want to read one row at a time. For your information, I'm doing one row at a time because it involves a few tables, each with billions of rows, and it takes forever if i join them or run complicated sqls. The bottom line is I need to keep sql as simple as possible.

This line however takes much longer than other sqls to execute. I think it's due to the nature of rownum as it looks up the whole table. Is it possible to optimize this sql or even without the use of rownum?

`id` is the primary key. If you need more information, please ask away!

edit: here's the code

```
for(int i = 1; i<=count; i++){
        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        String pid = ns.findPId(i); //find one pid at a time, average execution time ~130ms
        //sql: select id from (select id,rownum as rn from person_info) where rn=#{rowNum}
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("findPId(i)： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");

        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Genotype g = ns.findPersonInfo(pid); //obtain associated info, average execution time ~20ms
        endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("findPersonInfo(pid)： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");

        if(g!=null){
            if(g.getIdCardNumber()!=null && g.getIdCardNumber().matches(idCardNoEL)){ //valid card number
                startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                int isMatch = findPersonIdNoMatch(pid); //average execution time ~2ms
                endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                log.info("findPersonIdNoMatch(pid)： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
                if(isMatch == 0){ 
                    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    String sampleId = ns.findSampleIdByPid(pid); //average execution ~10ms
                    endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    log.info("findSampleIdByPid(pid)： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
                    if(sampleId!=null){
                        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Genotype temp = ns.findGeneInfoBySampleId(sampleId); //get geneinfo and createDateTime, average execution ~10ms
                        endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        log.info("findGeneInfoBySampleId(sampleId)： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
                        if(temp!=null){
                            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            g.setGeneInfo(temp.getGeneInfo());
                            g.setCreateDateTime(temp.getCreateDateTime());
                            endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            log.info("set： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
                            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            insertGenotype(g); //average execution 1ms
                            endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                            log.info("insertGenotype(g)： "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    //log
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `offset ... fetch first ... rows only`? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD But using a loop with SQL is usually a code smell. Doing things in set based approach without a loop is in most of the cases more efficient - but without your code this is impossible to answer

Comment: For oracle, when you want to use `rownum`, you have to use `ORDER BY`. Your code seems meaningless in this case. Could you post your loop here, or answer the question why you didn't get the id the same time you initial your loop instead of getting it inside your loop?

Comment: Is there any way you could create procedures on the database that encapsulate the database logic, so as to reduce the amount of data you're passing between the db and java?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't use fetch first without oracle 11

Comment: If you're running the query to find each person_info.id by passing in the rownum... why don't you open a ref cursor on the db to select all the relevant id rows, and then loop over that dataset. That means you're querying the table once, and simply retrieving each row as required - as per cocosnake's answer.

Comment: You implemented a very inefficient *DIY* `nested loop join`. You should check the  [JPA pagination](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-pagination-jpa-hibernate/) as a substitute for the main loop. This will enable the use of `offset ...`clause and processing of N rows in one step.  You'll have to define  a deterministic **order** of the processing of the rows in `person_info`. The next step would be to replace the single gets of additional tables with a joined access (you will see this a a problem only after you resolve the main problem with the loop).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I'm not using hibernate. I'm using mybatis

Comment: Well you are doing a *batch processing*, which is not very effective with any kind of **ORM**. I do not call it a *code smell* as @a_horse_with_no_name, but it is hard to achieve a good performance. Simple try a `SQL` only solution to see your benchmark and then re-think if you need `ORM`.

Answer (score 0):

you may prefer to run a simple query like

```
select id,rownum as rn from person_info
```

And iterate on it from you java code. Don't get all the result at once, but one row at a time.
You'll find more information here : https://dzone.com/articles/the-performance-difference-between-sql-row-by-row